# how retrieve data to form html with smarty?

Tags: smarty, prestashop

how retrieve data to form html with smarty in presta ?

Thanks

```
    <form action="" method="post">
         <input type="file" id="image"/>
         <button type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a variable in php first using the following in syntax

```
$smarty->assign('image',$imagename);
```

Now you can access the assigned variable in html as follows

```
<input type="file" id="image" value="{$image}" />
```

For further reference of using loops and other entities of smarty in prestashop go throught his url:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Theme+templates+and+Smarty